# Gnuplot multiple values in ytics

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I'm trying to display values in the **ytics** of a simple lines points graph in two different representations, in **days** and **years**.

My data file consists of two cols, each of which containing unix timestamps.

```
1580342400  1492387200
1583107200  1493856000
1584230400  1494201600
1585267200  1495238400
...
```

Here's what I did so far:

```
set term qt
set xlabel "Current Date"
set ylabel "Time to wait in days and years"
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%d.%m.\n%Y"
set xdata time
set grid

plot 'times.log' \
  u 1:(($1-$2)/86400)::yticlabels(sprintf("%d (%.1f)",(($1-$2)/86400),(($1-$2)/86400/365))) \
  with lp lw 2 lt 4 notitle
```

Which yields the following result:
[image: gnuplot-tics]

The only thing that really bugs me is that the ytics are not **distributed equidistantly**.

Is there any way to have my desired format and still remain equidistant ytics?

Another option that crossed my mind was using the new **stats** function together with a **for loop** iterating over all data sets and adding one tic label for each data set manually.

Any hint welcome, however, I'm not a big fan of perl/bash/etc. mixed with gnuplot, I'd like to keep it gnuplot only in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would be the following: take y-axis for the days and y2-axis for the years.
You have to link them, check `help link`. If you want the years also on the left side at the y-axis you can "cheat" e.g. with `set y2tics offset graph -1.105,0`.
You have to play with all the offsets and margins to get an optimum result.
I am not aware that there would be a simple automated solution with something like `set format y "%tD (%tY)" time` (actually, `%tY` is not a valid format specifier). Check `help format specifiers` and `help time_specifiers`.
Keep in mind that although the numbers for days will be equidistant, but the numbers of years won't because of rounding errors.

**Code:**

```
### days and years at the y-axis
reset session

DateStart = "01.01.2020"
DateEnd   = "01.10.2021"

myTimeFmt = "%d.%m.%Y"
set xrange[strptime(myTimeFmt,DateStart):strptime(myTimeFmt,DateEnd)]

# create some test data
set samples 20
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:($1*1.07+rand(0)*3*86400) w table
unset table

set lmargin 14
set xlabel "Current date"
set format x "%d.%m.\n%Y" time

set ylabel "Time to wait in days (years)" offset -5,0
set format y "%.0f"
set ytics offset -5,0

set link y2 via y/365.25 inverse y*365.25
set y2tics
set y2tics offset graph -1.105,0
set format y2 "(%0.2f)"
set grid x,y
set key noautotitle

plot $Data u 1:(($2-$1)/3600/24) w lp pt 7

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Days on y-axis and years on y2-axis offers the advantage to set the `y2tics` steps "independently" with even numbers, but of course, the grid will only fit to the y-axis. Furthermore, you don't have to fiddle around with offsets. Of course, you have to link the axis (check `help link`).

Concerning test data, you can plot or print into a table, check `help table` and `help set print`. Like you, I prefer to do everything (if possible) in gnuplot, however, sometimes it might get pretty complicated and lengthy.
Furthermore, when I post an answer on SO, I always try to give a "copy & paste & run" example. If I don't have enough OP's data, I typically include a generation of some (random) data which resembles the OP's data in order to get a reasonable looking demo graph. In your case, simply skip these test data lines and replace `$Data` in the plot command with your filename, in your case `'times.log'`.

**Code:**

```
### days at y-axis and years at y2-axis
reset session

DateStart = "01.01.2020"
DateEnd   = "01.10.2021"

myTimeFmt = "%d.%m.%Y"
set xrange[strptime(myTimeFmt,DateStart):strptime(myTimeFmt,DateEnd)]

# create some test data
set samples 20
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:($1*1.07+rand(0)*3*86400) w table
unset table

set xlabel "Current date"
set format x "%d.%m.\n%Y" time

set ylabel "Time to wait in days"
set format y "%.0f"
set ytics nomirror

set link y2 via y/365.25 inverse y*365.25
set y2label "Time to wait in years"
set y2tics 0.02
set format y2 "%0.2f"
set grid x,y
set key noautotitle

plot $Data u 1:(($2-$1)/3600/24) w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Funny, because I've tried plotting the data to two y-axes - days on the left, years on the right. But I always ended up with an offset between the two, because I didn't know the link-statement. I would even leave the years on the right side why not. Only thing I absolutely don't get is the part where you generate data into that table. Never seen that one before, either. Why random data? Can you elaborate a little on that? Thanks very much of course!

Comment: @mefiX thanks for your quick response. See modified answer...